# How to get tables from SQL to Angular viaDjango as backend by not using any models in Django,

Tags: sql, django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework

There a table in my SQL, I want this tables to get visible in Angular frontend, I am using Django as backend code.
I can do this by creating a models of this tables in Django model, and do crud operation to get this in angular. But porblem is that these tables can be N numbered so i can't create django models for all these tables. So i want to get it directly in Angular frontend without using Django models. How can i achieve it ? ANy Idea?

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).